# Display a custom message for each shipping method in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking to display a custom message when the customer chooses a shipping option on the cart and checkout page. There are 4 shipping options and each one has a specific message that needs to be displayed when they choose one of the options. Ideally, it would need to display on the cart and checkout pages.

I have seen some code before which relates to shipping classes but not shipping methods.

The code referred to above is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'cart_items_shipping_class_message', 20, 1 ); 
function cart_items_shipping_class_message( $cart ){
if ( is_admin() && ! defined('DOING_AJAX') )
    return;

$shipping_class = '150';

// Loop through cart items
foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
    
    if( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class() === $shipping_class ){
    wc_clear_notices();
            
    wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'Beers can only be shipped via <a title="Pallet Shiping" href="/shipping-delivery/#Pallet_Shipping" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Pallet Shiping</a>. To reveal much cheaper UPS Shipping Rates, remove Beers from the Cart.'), 'notice' );
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Mark